# How to prevent setmetatable to be overridden

Tags: security, lua, overriding, lua-table, metatable

I want to share content in a secure way without exposing it to malicious code. Let's say I have a

Base addon

```lua
local BaseAddon = {}
local secretTable = {someContent = "hidden content"}

local function index(t,k)
  if (k == "SECRET") then
    return secretTable
  end
end

setmetatable(BaseAddon, {
  __index = index,
  __newindex = function() end,
  __metatable  = false, -- disallow setmetatable again
})

return BaseAddon -- or a global hook method...
```

and a Sub addon that accesses the Base addon hidden content

```lua
local SubAddon = require("BaseAddon") -- or a global hook method...

SubAddon = SubAddon["SECRET"]
print(SubAddon.somelib) -- returns content

SubAddon = SubAddon["SECRETS"]
print(SubAddon.somelib) -- returns index local 'SubAddon' (a nil value)
```

but this is still not safe. I could now just simply do the following to catch my secret:

```lua
function newSetmetatable(table, mt)
    mt.__metatable = nil
    mt.__index = function(t,k)
      print(k)
      return t[k]
    end
    return originalSetmetatable (table, mt)
end
originalSetmetatable = setmetatable
setmetatable = newSetmetatable
```

Is there any way to prevent this or another solution to actually share the secret table?

Answer (score 0):

Your original code is as good as you can get in Lua. Any sort of security like that you set up in Lua needs to either be written in C, or be ran before any untrusted code runs.